# how to select orders that contains certain sku

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find items that contain SKUs starting with AB but would still want the query to return orders that contains AB and others.

```
order number 12334: sku AB12 & AB24
order number 22356: sku AB523 & KC5145              
order number 123556: sku CD5641 & BG521
```

I expect the query to return order number 12334 and 22356 but not 123556

I would also like to know if an order is purely AB or AB with other items
so the table would return count of orders that contains only AB and count of order that contains AB with other items.

I have two tables: an `orders` table and `line_items`

`orders` table gives `order_id` to link to `line_items` table ID

```
select * from xx.line_items l
left join xx.orders o on l.order_id=o.id
where sku like 'AB%'
```

Comment: Please show us your code and where you are stuck.

Comment: What tables do you have?  What are their columns?  What do you want returned?

Comment: i have two tables. orders table and line item table

orders table gives order ID to link to line item table ID

select * from xx.line_items l
left join xx.orders o on l.order_id=o.id
where sku like 'AB%'

Comment: but that would only give me orders with AB i cant tell if that order contains just AB or other items as well..

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared much details about the tables and columns for us to provide the full solution, but see if you can build something off of this mock up

```
select 
sku,
(char_length(sku)-char_length(replace(sku,'AB','')))/2 as item_count 
from your_table 
where sku like '%AB%';
```

Answer (score 0):

he following query gives you all order IDs with AB items. It shows their AB count and their total count, so you can compare the two. You could also add a `CASE WHEN` expression to compute a flag showing whether the order is pure AB or not.

After all this simply groups the items per order, counts AB items and dismisses all orders that have no AB item.

```
select
  order_id,
  count(*) as count_all,
  count(case when sku like 'AB%' then 1 end) as count_ab
from line_items
group by order_id
having count(case when sku like 'AB%' then 1 end) > 0;
```

You can replace `count(case when sku like 'AB%' then 1 end)` with `sum(sku like 'AB%')` in MySQL by the way.

Here is a query building up on the above to count pure AB orders and mixed orders:

```
select (count_all = count_ab) as ab_only, count(*)
from
(
  select count(*) as count_all, count(case when sku like 'AB%' then 1 end) as count_ab
  from line_items
  group by order_id
  having count(case when sku like 'AB%' then 1 end) > 0
) counted
group by (count_all = count_ab);
```